# dica de implementação

Tags: php, javascript

Eu fiz um página usando a tag `<video>`, conforme código abaixo:

```js
function teste(){
var url = document.getElementById('mudarVideo').value;
if(url === '')
{
 alert('campo Vazio');
} else {
     videoConteudo = document.getElementById('meuVideo');
    videoConteudo.pause();
    document.querySelector("#meuVideo > source").src = url;
 videoConteudo.load();
 }    
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
<input type="text" id="mudarVideo" value="">
<input type="button" id="btn-insere" onclick="teste()" value="Inserir novo video"/>
<video autoplay loop width="960" height="540" id="meuVideo">
 <source src="http://www.jennylynpereira.com/demo/html/awesome-photography3/html/videos/video.mp4" id="tv_main_channel">
</video>
</div>
```

Eu queria fazer algo interativo, assim que o usuário colocar uma url do vídeo lá no `input` `mudarVideo` (por exemplo: techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4), o site vai ser atualizado com o novo conteúdo, essa implementação foi feita em javascript e está funcionando, mas não tem interação dinâmica.

Para fazer isso, eu devo criar um banco de dados com uma tabela que irá receber a url (tipo `VARCHAR`) e depois armazenar essa url no banco? Ai depois é só fazer um `SELECT` dessa url e adicionar no lugar do url, não é?

```
document.querySelector("#meuVideo > source").src = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer o seguinte, adicionar um listener no input mudarVideo que executa quando seu texto for alterado. Esse listener executa uma função que é "debounced", ou seja, só executa depois de x milisegundos sem nenhuma ação para impedir que o video fique mudando enquanto o usuário digita.

```
<div class="center">
    <input type="text" id="mudarVideo" onchange="onUrlChange()" value="">
    <input type="button" id="btn-insere" onclick="teste()" value="Inserir novo video"/>

    <video autoplay loop width="960" height="540" id="meuVideo">
        <source src="http://www.jennylynpereira.com/demo/html/awesome-photography3/html/videos/video.mp4" id="tv_main_channel">
    </video>
</div>
<script>
    function debounce(fn, delay) {
        var timer = null;
        return function () {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            clearTimeout(timer);
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                fn.apply(context, args);
            }, delay);
        };
    }

    var changeVideoSource = debounce(function(url) {
        document.querySelector("#meuVideo > source").src = url;
    }, 800);

    function onTextChange() {
        var url = document.getElementById('mudarVideo').value;
        if (url.length > 0) {
            changeVideoSource(url);
        }
    }

    function teste(){
        var url = document.getElementById('mudarVideo').value;
        if(url === '')
        {
            alert('campo Vazio');
        } else {
            var videoConteudo = document.getElementById('meuVideo');
            videoConteudo.pause();
            document.querySelector("#meuVideo > source").src = url;
            videoConteudo.load();
        }
    }
</script>
```